# How to write test for a function that has no input and inside a class in python

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I want to write a test for a function but that function is inside a class and has no input, how do I write it?

This is the function:

```
def add_video_to_playlist(self):
        number_to_add = self.input_vide0_add_txt.get()
        video_to_add = lib.get_name(number_to_add)
        play_count = lib.get_play_count(number_to_add)
        if video_to_add is not None:
            self.playlist.append(video_to_add)
            set_text(self.playlist_txt, self.playlist)
            messagebox.showinfo("Play count", print(play_count))
        else:
            set_text(self.playlist_txt, f"Video {number_to_add} not found")
```

And this is the class of the function:

```
class CreateVideoList():
    def __init__(self, window):
        window.geometry("1000x600")
        window.title("Check Videos")
        window.configure(background= "#333333")

        self.playlist = []

        enter_playlist_name_lbl = Label(window, text="Enter Playlist's name", background="#458B74")
        enter_playlist_name_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=24, pady=24)

        self.name_txt = Entry(window, width=30)
        self.name_txt.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=24, pady=24)

        create_video_list_btn = Button(window, text="Create Video List", background="#458B74", command=self.create_playlist_clicked)
        create_video_list_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=24, pady=24)

        list_videos_btn = Button(window, text="List All Videos in the library", command=self.list_videos_clicked,  background="#458B74")
        list_videos_btn.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=24, pady=24)

        self.list_txt = tkst.ScrolledText(window, width=48, height=12, wrap="none")
        self.list_txt.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="W", padx=9, pady=9)

        enter_video_to_add_lbl = Label(window, text="Enter Video Number to add to new playlist",  background="#458B74")
        enter_video_to_add_lbl.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=24, pady=24)

        self.input_vide0_add_txt = Entry(window, width=7)
        self.input_vide0_add_txt.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=9, pady=9)

        add_button = Button(window, text="Add", background="#458B74", command=self.add_video_to_playlist)
        add_button.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=9, pady=9)

        self.playlist_txt = tkst.ScrolledText(window, width=48, height=12, wrap="none")
        self.playlist_txt.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky="W", padx=9, pady=9)

        play_button = Button(window, text="Play", background="#458B74")
        play_button.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=9, pady=9)


    def list_videos_clicked(self):
        video_list = lib.list_all()
        set_text(self.list_txt, video_list)


    def create_playlist_clicked(self):
        playlist_name = self.name_txt.get()
        if playlist_name == None:
            raise ValueError("Name cannot be NULL")
        set_text(self.playlist_txt, playlist_name)

    
    


    def add_video_to_playlist(self):
        number_to_add = self.input_vide0_add_txt.get()
        video_to_add = lib.get_name(number_to_add)
        play_count = lib.get_play_count(number_to_add)
        if video_to_add is not None:
            self.playlist.append(video_to_add)
            set_text(self.playlist_txt, self.playlist)
            messagebox.showinfo("Play count", print(play_count))
        else:
            set_text(self.playlist_txt, f"Video {number_to_add} not found")


    def play_playlist(self):
        for i in self.playlist.keys():
            lib.increment_play_count(i)
        messagebox.showinfo("Notification", "Playlist is playing")
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you find something hard to test, it is possible that your code needs some refactoring. In this particular case, I'd say `__init__()` (and hence this class) is responsible for way too many things.

Comment: You do not test a function, only its behaviour under defined circumstances. Here the *context* is the `self.input_vide0_add_txt` Entry field and the `lib` *thing*. A common testing method would be to mock both (meaning provides mock objects that will have some defined behaviour) and assert that you correctly add the expected value to `self.playlist`, and call the expected functions (here again a mock library can help). That being said, mixing interactive input and internal processing in the same method is generally seen as bad according to the single concern principle...

Comment: What is set problem exactly, what do you wanna test for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.